# Invalid expression passing props in vue.js template - IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and I'm trying to create a Vue component.

```
Vue.component('sales-report', {
  data: function() { 
    return { products: products, seasons: seasons }
  },
  template: '<course-details-menu :dropdown-data="{ products, outlineClassifications, seasons, years }"></course-details-menu>'
});
```

This is a simplified example of my app, and it works in Chrome, but in IE, I get this error from Vue:

> Error compiling template:: 
>   - invalid expression: :dropdown-data="{ products, seasons }"
>   found in ---> `<SalesReport>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IE11 doesn't support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) the ECMAScript 2015 property name shorthand.

You'll need to explicitly state the object's key-values like this:

```
:dropdown-data="{ products: products, seasons: seasons }"
```

Comment: Ah - duh. Thanks! Spent too much time debugging this!